# Does Skyrim for PC support command line options?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Ideally, I'd like to use a command line option to automatically resume the most recent save game.  This would essentially be the equivalent of clicking "Continue" from the game's opening menu.  Although I am mainly interested in a command line option that supports that feature, I'd really like to see a list of all command line options.

Comment: Have you tried appending ` /?` to the command line?

Comment: Good idea, but all it does it run the EXE, although that doesn't necessarily mean anything.  They probably just didn't write in any friendly command line validation with the expectation that gamers aren't going to get all DOSsy with Skyrim.

Comment: Bump (or at least seeing if questions can be bumped by a comment). Been almost 7 years and I find myself asking about command line options again.

Comment: Special edition : [AutoLoad](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/41478) "Windows command file that automatically loads saved games upon game launch in Bethesda games." ... But not with a CL, these type of mods use hacks : "batch key strokes" and "simulate a mouseclick" - Answer to the title is no. Answer to the body is mods.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a mod to support this functionality.
Not tested by myself...

[Skyrim Skip Launcher Mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/1068/?)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the Gamebryo/Creation engines to indicate any command line parameters, things like `+fullproc` and `+highprio` work only for other engines. All arguments used at game launch are encapsulated in the Skyrim.ini and SkyrimPrefs.ini files.
However, there are plenty of [command line options](https://falloutck.uesp.net/wiki/Talk:Creation_Kit) for the Creation Kit (to be tested), and options also available for running the [Papyrus compiler](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Papyrus_Compiler_Reference#Running_the_compiler) either within or outside the Creation Kit.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, newer games are not coded to include outside parameters into their command line start options. There is, however, a command console inside of the game ( available [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)) ), but I sense that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Most new games I know of support command-line options.  It's really not that difficult to code them...

Comment: "Unfortunately, newer games are not coded to include outside parameters into their command line start options." - it *really* depends on the game.

Comment: @AnnaLear - it does, however I cannot name any in the past year that I have played that have them. BlueRaja - I said nothing about difficulty to code them.

Comment: Pretty much every Source game supports CL options..

Comment: i think it really depends on the dev group and engine. valve seems to like them, Bethesda not so much.

Comment: @TrewTzu ID Engine has them. That is BEthesda too ;)

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness the various [id Tech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Tech) game engines are by id Software, not Bethesda. Bethesda just publishes some of idS's games, they don't code them.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie They are owned by Bethesda though, which makes them Bethesda :P

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Bethesda don't own id Software, they're just the publisher of *some* of their games. Further, Bethesda has literally nothing to do with the id Tech 5 engine. That makes it **not** Bethesda. (What's more — relevant to these comments — Valve's Source Gold engine is an id Tech engine as well.)